# how can I remove and wipe out saved data on usb device in Android Studio when running a code?

Tags: android, android-studio

My code uses shared preferences and  local db and saves some data on my usb device.
I wanna to run my code from scratch every time.
and these saved data be clear.

For now I go to setting on my device , in 'Apps' section , find my app , and touch 'clear data' button to remove these saved data.

Is there any way in Android Studio to wipe out user data ?
I checked 'Wipe User Data' in emulator tab but it doesn't work , I think it works only for emulators not usb devices.

Comment: you will have to uninstall the app first, as android studio only calls install and its up to the device to determine that the app is exits or no to install/update.

Comment: @k0sh you say that isn't any solution to install app from scratch directly  from android studio without uninstall it on the device ?

Comment: yup, unless if you find something can do that, please let me know. its interesting. however android studio is developed by android, maybe if we issued ticket they might integrate their uninstall apk with the IDE? i doubt it lol

Answer (score 4):

Stop your emulator.
Open the android virtual device manager from Tools > Android > AVD Manager.
There you can see your emulator(example:nexus).
Press the arrow in the right side and choose wipe data.
That's all open again the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Today, Open the android, in the top bar go to **Tools** select **Device Manager**, after click on arrow (this item is at the right of the device selection), and finally click on **wipe data**.
That's all.