# Wipe user data Android studio 2.2.3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I am trying to find a way to wipe user data from my Android studio Emulator. the AVD manager shows no option like that. Can someone please help me.

-- Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Its already answered here..

[how can I remove and wipe out saved data on usb device in Android Studio when running a code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30974791/how-can-i-remove-and-wipe-out-saved-data-on-usb-device-in-android-studio-when-ru)

Stop your emulator. Open the android virtual device manager from android studio menu. There you can see your emulator(example:nexus). Press the arrow in the right side and choose wipe data. That's all open again the emulator.